# How to read the code of a contract deployed on vechain

Tags: blockchain

I tried to read the code of a contract deployed on Vechain by using vechain-explore. For example how do I convert the code on the photo to something readable? I tried using conversion from hexadecimal to text but it doesnt work.

[image: contract bytecode]

Comment: You can easlity get an opcode view, or an approximate `solidity` like syntax. Which one are you looking for ?

Comment: Solidity like would be definitely better.

Comment: The best I know of is this one : https://ethervm.io/decompile but it's not actual solidity , you do need to spend a bit of time on it to really understand what it does, but it's better than nothing.